# recover my calendar appointments

Tags: iphone

I was entering a new appointment on my Iphone6 and was interrupted by a phone call. After the call I went back to check my calendar and all of my existing appointments had disappeared. They first appeared then disappeared. What happened and how do I recover my appointments?

Comment: Open Calender and press "Calenders" just above the home button, and make sure the correct calenders are enabled.  Most people don't realize that there are multiple calendars.

Comment: also try in the "Calendars" Menu to pull down to force a refresh :)